# StorageProviderSyncRootManager UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, uwp

I create a simple UWP project, and I ready to use [StorageProviderSyncRootManager Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.provider.storageprovidersyncrootmanager?view=winrt-20348) in my uwp project.

But throw an exception below. Who can help me to resolve it, pls...

[image]

Comment: have you tried to run visual studio as administrator ?

Comment: I've tried run vs as administrator, but same

Comment: This is a known issue here: [Github issue#402](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/issues/402). It's a Windows platform issue that has already been logged.